# Why is there a copy of native shared libraries in both system APKs and /system/lib/?

Tags: android-source

When I look at the directory `/system/lib/` I see libbluetooth_jni.so, I also see the same file inside the Bluetooth.apk in `/system/app/`. Seems like an unnecessary duplication. Why is it included in two places? Which one is actually used by the application when the code runs?

Answer (score 0):

In case your application is in system/app, it will use the library from system/lib.
If you install the apk, then the installer will put the apk into /data/app and unpack the library into a special place in data which will be used for this app.

There is some logic in doing that because the compiler does not know beforehand if you put it as a system or data app. So in any case it will put the lib into apk.

BTW. Apk in system/app will crash if not having its lib in system.

Comment: The android platform build system does know beforehand that APKs it builds are destined for `/system/app` (or `/system/priv-app`) and not `/data/app`, thus you cannot argue that it needs to put the native library in the APK just in case.

Comment: You are right. It knows in the build environment. But it doesnt really change the compilation process. So bottomline the apks result is the same. I can only guess why it remains like this.